# Does omitting sign automatically default to signed variable in C?

Tags: c

Is `long == signed long` (`int`, `char`, etc)?

Is this guaranteed by the specification or is there some obscure version or compiler that will blow up if I take this for granted.

Comment: No. not with bit fields.

Comment: @chux Wise master Yoda, I would really appreciate if you spoke in less cryptic tongue. My young padawan mind cannot comprehend your great brilliance.

Comment: A bit field is a special case which allows you to specify how many bits are required for the range of values you want to store in a variable. The top-rated answer to this is correct, but if you are using bit fields (you can google this - they have a very specific syntax) then there seems to be implementation-defined behavior associated with signed/unsigned interpretation.

Comment: [enum's signness is also implementation defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2579230/995714)

Comment: Not mentioned yet, bit-fields may either be signed or unsigned if not explicitly specified

Comment: @AlanSTACK [re](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) Yoda sleep he must too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes for all the types you list, other than `char`.

`char` is signed or unsigned in an implementation defined manner. Furthermore, `char` is an entirely distinct type from `singed char` and `unsigned char`, even though it will have the exact same properties as one of them.

You may think I'm talking crazy here, but here it is straight from the C standard:

**6.2.5 Types - p15**

> The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are collectively
>   called the character types. The implementation shall define char to
>   have the same range, representation, and behavior as either signed
>   char or unsigned char.

Comment: [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/995714)

Answer (score 3):

Yes following two variable definitions are same:

```
long x = 9;
signed long x = 9;
```

`signed` keyword is unnecessary here because variables are `signed` by default except `char`. If you need to use `unsigned` then you need to explicitly use `unsigned` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

> Does omitting `signed` automatically default to signed variable in C?

Yes, usually, but no in general.  **Exceptions**:

1. A  `char` is a distinct type from `unsigned char`, and `signed char`.  `char` will have the same range as `unsigned char` or  `signed char`.
2. `wchar_t` follows a similar 3-ness like `char`.
3. Bit fields.

Key citations about bit fields indicate an `int` bit field may be signed or unsigned.  It is implementation defined behavior.   [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23987436/2410359). The use of `long`, `unsigned long` and `unsigned long` if allowed, would incur implementation defined behavior.

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type. C11dr §6.7.2.1 5
>
> A bit-field is interpreted as having a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the specified number of bits.<sup>125</sup> §6.7.2.1 10
>
> <sup>125</sup> As specified in 6.7.2 above, if the actual type specifier used is `int` or ..., then it is implementation-defined whether the bit-field is signed or unsigned.

4. Other exceptions may exist - yet I do not know of them.